# Generic way to describe data for cross-platform cross-database cross-language system

Tags: database, cross-platform

What is the most generic way of describe data (*without logic attached*) that can be shared between systems on different platforms, databases, all written in different languages?

My takes on so far:

1. JSON

   - Pros:

     - Implementation for most systems
     - Readable for human
     - Reasonable fast
   - Cons:

     - Hard to scale up (too much data!)
     - No standard way to validate semantics
     - No standard way to present for non-technical user
2. XML

   - Pros:

     - Implementation for most systems
     - Readable for human
     - Easy to validate (schema)
     - Resonable easy to present for non-technical user (XSLT)
   - Cons:

     - Slower than JSON
     - Even less scallable up than JSON
3. Flatbuffers

   - Pros:

     - Convertable to JSON (you keep all advantage of JSON)
     - Lighting fast!
     - Support some degree of reflection
     - Very small footprint for data (especially large one)
   - Cons:

     - Not-so-good support outside C++
     - No conversion to XML
     - Data are not readable at all (until converted to JSON)

Anything else? I'll update the list as answer will come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try my [FastBinaryEncoding](https://github.com/chronoxor/FastBinaryEncoding) serialization format

4. FastBinaryEncoding

   - Proc:

     - Cross platform (Linux, OSX, Windows)
     - Generators for C++, C#, Go, Java, JavaScript, Kotlin, Python, Ruby
     - Native structs, classes and containers for each language
     - Support of all common data types, enums, flags and collections
     - Structs nesting
     - Ultra-fast binary serialization/deserialization
     - JSON serialization/deserialization
     - [Versioning solution](https://github.com/chronoxor/FastBinaryEncoding#versioning)
     - [Excellent performance](https://github.com/chronoxor/FastBinaryEncoding#performance-benchmarks)
   - Cons:

     - Data are not human-readable (until converted to JSON)